# File 'login.module.ts' is not a module

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Typescript and Angular 4. I am trying to access the class object which I created in the path `/ClientApp/app/_models/login.module`.
My login.module.ts code is as below

```
module loginApp {
    export class LoginModel {
        public MID: string;
        public Password: string;
    }
}
```

And my component code where i am trying to import login.module.ts is `/ClientApp/app/components/login/login.component.ts`.

Below is the  code for login.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { login1 } from '../../_models/login.module'

@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html'
})
export class LoginComponent {
    public isLoggedIn: boolean;
    public login() {
        //loginModel: LoginModel = new LoginModel();
        //loginModel.MID = this.mid;
        //loginModel.Password = this.password;
    }
}
```

Now when i am trying to execute i am getting below error while importing the login.module. Below is the error message

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./ClientApp/app/components/login/login.component.ts:4:24 
TS2306: File 'D:/Study/FSE/Angular_With_Core/Angular_With_Core/ClientApp/app/_models/login.module.ts' is not a module.
```

How to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want make a class for the loginModel type, like so:

```
 export class LoginModel {
  MID: string;
  Password: string;
}
```

And import it in your login.component.ts like so:

```
import { LoginModel } from '../LoginModel';
```

Ideally you would save this as LoginModel.ts or for better practice create a folder called "models" and have each standalone object type in its own file.

*Have a look at the [Angular Tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1) on how to import the class as a model, if my answer didn't cover everything you were looking for.*

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18073203)

Comment: Fair enough, changed the answer accordingly.